# Как сделать так, чтобы при создании страницы курсор не находился в TextBox? C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asp.net, textbox

У меня создан TextBox, в котором по умолчанию находится текст. При открытии страницы текст в этом TextBox автоматически полностью выделяется. мне нужно чтобы по умолчанию курсор как бы находился по середине страницы. Как это можно сделать?
C# Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в свойствах каждого `TextBox` выставить значение `TabStop` на `false`.